# Sources on dictionary learning and related algorithms

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, image-processing

In the context of signal processing and sparse representation of signals, there is a topic called dictionary learning which is basically about how to's of the selection of basis functions used for sparse representation. I am looking for sources explaining the topic with a section on dictionary learning algorithms and probably a comparison made among them.

Answer (score 1):

The best resource, in my opinion, is [eDx - Sparse Representations in Signal and Image Processing: Fundamentals](https://www.edx.org/course/sparse-representations-in-signal-and-image-processing-fundamentals) by [Michael Elad](https://elad.cs.technion.ac.il/).